# Random walk on a graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk

For a random walk say from point $x$ to $y$ on a graph,

How is the probability of a Random walker reaching point $y$ before returning to $x$ related to the expected of the number of visits to point $x$, $E(T_{x})$ and the  expected number of visits to y, $E(T_{y})$ after infinitely many steps?
(If there does exist one can you please prove it)

Comment: with classical notations, $ET_x$ is the average time to return to $x$ starting from $x$.

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: so, not the expected number of visits.

Comment: well i was kinda assuming they're the same

Comment: isn't the number of visits infinite?

Comment: well no that's the problem
the result is actually inversely proportional to the difference of the two expectations